# Cannot load a profile specific properties file with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties-file, spring-profiles

I'm trying to use @Value to load properties from profile specific properties files under resources dir, but I'm getting "could not resolve propertyPlaceHolder". Below is my code.

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.my.package")
@Import({DevConfig.class,QAConfig.class}
@SpringBootApplicaton()
public class Config(){
   @Value("${someProperty"})
   private String property;

   @Bean
   public void getProperty(){
     return property;
   }
   //other beans
}
```

DevConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@Profile("dev")
public class DevConfig {
    @Bean
    public static PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer properties() {
    PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer ppc = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
    Resource[] resources = new ClassPathResource[] { new ClassPathResource("dev/application-dev.properties") };
    ppc.setLocations(resources);
    ppc.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
    return ppc;
    }
}
```

MainClass

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Config.class);

        SomeBean bean = context.get("beanName",SomeBean.class);
        //logic follows
    }
}
```

I do this because I need to run this as a standalone app.I know something is wrong with this but I don't know what.

Answer (score 2):

With Spring Boot a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` is created for you automatically.

If you wish to define a custom location for your properties file(s) you can use the following annotation.

```
@PropertySource("classpath:foo.properties")
```

*(Just add the annotation on class level to your configuration class, it is also Spring profile aware - different locations for different environments.)*

Answer (score 0):

Try moving `dev/application-dev.properties` directly inside `src/main/resources`